# jQuery ().on Syntax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I'm making a gif search engine using the giphy api and jQuery.  every time a topic is searched for, jQuery creates a topic button for the topic entered and loads in the respective gifs when said button is pressed. when loading in the gifs from the topic button. im confused why this works:

```
$(document).on("click", ".topic", displayGifs);
```

but this doesn't:

```
$(".topic").on('click', function(event) {
    displayGifs();
})
```

any help on this topic would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Look into *event delegation in jQuery* Google it. There are plenty of answers in SO as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first sample delegates the event to the `document` object. Since that is a static element, any new elements that are added to the DOM which match the delegate selector (in this case `.topic`), the event binding will still trigger.

Your second example will only bind to elements that exist within the DOM at the time of binding.

Read more about [event delegation in jQuery](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).